# How to update field in table Laravel or create?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I try to update field `rate` in table by primary key `user_id`.

So, I need to increment of decrement `rate` field. If row is not exist I need to create it.

I tried:

```
$this->point = -1; // Or $this->point = 1;
Rating::updateOrCreate(["user_id", $id], ["rate" => $this->point]);
```

But it does not work:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `rating` where (`0` = user_id and `1` = 5) limit 1)
```

Comment: Could you provide the method of `Rating::updateOrCreate`, as that's the code being used.

Comment: This is just model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your passing the column and the value as two separate values.

Change:

```
["user_id", $id]
```

to:

```
["user_id" => $id]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works, but how I can update +-1, I mean increment and decrement?

Comment: [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate) states the first parameter as attributes and the second as values, try:
`Rating::updateOrCreate(["user_id", "rate"], [$id, $this->point]);`

Comment: @MarcHerzog Yeah, as in the first param you pass to `updateOrCreate` is an array of the key value pairs that are pre-existing attributes in the table and the second param is an array of key value pairs that you want to use to update that row.

Comment: @Darama I would personally set a default value on the column in your migrations and then use `firstOrCreate` instead of `updateOrCreate`. Then when you have the model you can then use the `increment` or `decrement` methods. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#increment-and-decrement) e.g. `$rating->increment('rate', 1);`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel (eloquent) provides a fluent way to update related models.
Assuming the following model structure:

Rating.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User.php

```
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rating');
}
```

You can easily update the relation via `associate()`

```
$user = User::findOrFail($userId);
$rating = Rating::findOrFail($ratingId);  

$rating->user()->associate($user)->save();
```

Read more about [Relationships in Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships)